# Write to Azure documentDb with SeriLog

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, serilog

I have setup a database with a collection in Azure with DocumentDB. I can connect, query, update do the whole CRUD thing with the database. Now I'm adding seriLog so I can log errors to my new database. SeriLog has a sink for Azure DocumentDb. You can install it via NuGet:

```
       Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb
```

After doing so, I do the following as a test to write something to my database via seriLog:

```
                Uri uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]);
        DateTimeOffset timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
        Exception exception = new Exception("This is just a test");
        IEnumerable<MessageTemplateToken> tokens = new List<MessageTemplateToken>();
        MessageTemplate messageTemplate = new MessageTemplate(tokens);
        IEnumerable<LogEventProperty> properties = new List<LogEventProperty>();
        LogEvent logEvent = new LogEvent(timestamp, LogEventLevel.Information,exception,messageTemplate,properties);
        var azure = new AzureDocumentDBSink(uri, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"], "Items",null);
        azure.Emit(logEvent);
```

When i try to compile this project, I get the following:

```
    Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDB' with identity  
    'Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDB, Version=1.5.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' uses 'Serilog,  
     Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' 
     which has a higher version than referenced assembly 
    'Serilog' with identity 'Serilog, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
    PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10'
```

I looked in the app.config and saw the following:

```
       <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Serilog" publicKeyToken="24c2f752a8e58a10" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.0.0" newVersion="1.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Normally when this happens, I just update the reference and i'm good to go. But this isn't the case. I started with a blank console app in VS2015, installed the NuGet package, added the code and tried to run it. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the package's NuSpec; it's fixed in *Serilog.Sinks.DocumentDB* version 1.5.8, which is now published.

```
Update-Package Serilog
Update-Package Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDB
```

In the *Package Manager Console* (VS) will sort it out.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas..I tweeted you about this and you responded there as well. Its working!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting Serilog as well as Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb packages, and then adding Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb back?